# Add an absolute selector in a nested style

Tags: css, less

I am trying to figure out the best way to accomplish reusing some of the nested styles in Less to prevent duplication, but I am not sure if I have found the best way.

Right now I have something like:

```
.category-link,
.caption-link {
    background-color: @linkColour;
    font-family: @linkFont;
    max-width:2em;
    a {
        /* INNER LINK STYLES */
        text-decoration:none;
        white-space:nowrap;
        /* ...INNER LINK STYLES CONTINUE... */
    }
}
```

Now I want to apply those same inner link styles to the selector `.action-link a` without applying the outer styles to `.action-link`.

I get my intended output if I do it this way:

```
.inner-link-styles() {
    /* INNER LINK STYLES */
    text-decoration:none;
    white-space:nowrap;
    /* ...INNER LINK STYLES CONTINUE... */
}
.category-link,
.caption-link {
    background-color: @linkColour;
    font-family: @linkFont;
    max-width:2em;
    a {
        .inner-link-styles;
    }
}
.action-link a {
    .inner-link-styles;
}
```

which doesn't require any duplication, but I'd prefer to keep those styles in their current location, where they are relevant, than to move them out to `mixins.less` and increase complexity for the next developer to troubleshoot.

What felt intuitive, but is clearly wrong, was something like this:

```
.category-link,
.caption-link {
    background-color: @linkColour;
    font-family: @linkFont;
    max-width:2em;
    & a,
    .action-link a {
        /* INNER LINK STYLES */
        text-decoration:none;
        white-space:nowrap;
        /* ...INNER LINK STYLES CONTINUE... */
    }
}
```

but is there some other prefix I can apply to a selector to have it based absolutely, rather than relative to it's nesting level?

Comment: I think its not possible . The solution given by yourself is only one to go.

Comment: I had the feeling that might be the case... I feel like maybe once I have gotten more used to LESS I will stop wanting to use it in ways that don't gel with it. Do you (or anyone else) have any personal/coding style thoughts on whether the definition of `.inner-link-styles()` should go with other, more functional mixins in a separate file (`mixins.less`), go into their own separate file (`reusable.less`), or remain nearby the styles that actually use them? (Whether just from your own preferences based on experience or some formally defined best practice)

Comment: As for "should go with other, more functional mixins in a separate file (mixins.less)". Absolutely no. Any mixin should be in the place where you feel it belongs, mechanical structuring like "mixins should be in 'mixins', variables in 'variables' etc." is at least dumb and anti-productive. Never blindly copy certain approaches from famous frameworks (most of modern frameworks are designed by a small teams (down to 1 person) and there're a lot of anti-patterns).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolute selectors can't be added within a nested block because once we nest it under another block, the inner selector is considered as a child of  the outer one (like in the DOM) unless we add `&.` to the selector (in which case, the inner one could be another class on the parent itself).

Using **mixins** or the **`:extend`** feature are the best options for your case because you are assigning a set of common properties to multiple elements.

---

Since parent selector is known (it is either `.category-link a` or `.caption-link a`), you can extend the properties of that selector into `.action-link a` also. This would extend only the properties of the inner link and not that of its parent.

I don't think this increases the complexity for the next developer to troubleshoot because changing the properties in the original `.category-link a` will change the properties for `.action-link a` also.

```
.category-link,
.caption-link {
    background-color: blue;
    font-family: Arial;
    max-width:2em;
    a {
        /* INNER LINK STYLES */
        text-decoration:none;
        white-space:nowrap;
        /* ...INNER LINK STYLES CONTINUE... */
    }
}
.action-link {
  a {
    &:extend(.category-link a);
  }
}
```

Comment: This would appear to be exactly what I was looking for! I'm looking into documentation of this feature now, and in case it helps anyone else, the revelatory concept for me came from [css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/the-extend-concept/) - "a rule of thumb is: any time you'd use a mixin with no parameter, an extend will be more efficient". I'd found the parameter-less mixin way of doing it but it felt inelegant - this is the elegant solution. Thanks muchly